# Option "when I close the lid" missing on power settings after update from Win 7 to Win 10

Tags: sleep, lenovo-laptop

Option "when I close the lid" is missing on power settings on my Lenovo Thinkpad W541 after update from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Do you know how I can put it back? When I close the lid my laptop goes to sleep, but I plug it in an external monitor so I do not want that to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `Power and Sleep Settings` > Click `Additional Power Settings` > Click `Choose what closing the lid does` (it's on the left hand side of pane). There are options for both when the laptop is on battery or plugged in.